# Magento 1.9 404 Error in Magento Connect Manager

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, error, magento-connect, downloader

I have been having some issues with my magento connect manager. I feel like i have tried everything so I am reaching out for some help. Things I have tried...

1. Resetting Permissions in the folder and file
2. Took a folder from a fresh magento download and replaced it.
3. Clear cache, log out log back in.

I'm not even sure when it happened.

I'm thinking it could be my .htaccess maybe?

When I try to access it from the backend it redirects and gives me a 404 error on the front end and has this in the url.   /extension_local/index/key/0f705abce4703672f731b6f12f42681d/

If someone could help or have any suggestions I would appreciate it!

Comment: do you have access directly to it ? , did you try with `index.php` before downloader url ?

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the controller `Mage_Connect_Adminhtml_Extension_LocalController` is not available. Please make sure that you did not delete or deactivate `Mage_Connect`:

- `app/code/core/Mage/Connect` should exist and be readable
- The module should not be deactivated in `app/etc/modules` (check all XML files)

Answer (score 4):

Did all the above, but realised I was using Nginx and so it turned out to be not loading the default /downloader/index.php automatically.

Accessing the connect manager directly worked for me: www.example.com/downloader/index.php

Then added some restrictions in nginx conf to restrict to my IP address ore present basic auth login:-

```
location ~ /downloader/ {
    satisfy all;
    allow 1.2.3.4; #SET TO YOUR IP
    deny all;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd; #path to your password file, if there is one!
    autoindex off;
}
```

Comment: Amazing! +1 for thinking about security

Answer (score 3):

1 Download magento in https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/

2. delete the download folder on your server, replacing by the newly downloaded magento.

NOTE: Replace only the download folder.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. Solved it by accessing using regular HTTP instead of HTTPS.